# Loading Android Vector Drawable from a location other than res/drawables

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to use the new VectorDrawableCompat to handle SVGs that were converted to the Android Vector format. I followed the setup instructions as mentioned on the Android Developer Blog [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) and I am able to display a vector drawable that way. Although most of the time, this is how I will need to display most of the icons/images in the app, I do have a need to load a certain list of images from a server that can change frequently. The main reason for this is so that I don't need to post an update to the app just to change/add an icon.

As a test, I am trying to load the same format (Android Vector Drawable format) from Assets and when VectorDrawableCompat tries to generate the attribute set for the xml in order to pull out the attributes in the tags I get a runtime exception trying to cast XmlPullAttributes to XmlBlockParser:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5849)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:763)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.obtainAttributes(Resources.java:1896)
                                                                                     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCommon.obtainAttributes(VectorDrawableCommon.java:43)
                                                                                     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:469)
                                                                                     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
                                                                                     at com.mobile.hilton.amentiesicontestr.MainActivity.createFromXmlStream(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                                     at com.mobile.hilton.amentiesicontestr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6570)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5849) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:763) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
```

It is complaining, I believe, because it cannot find the Android namespace the VectorDrawable XML references. Normally the drawables are pre-compiled and in this case, my xml is not. Any thoughts on how to get around this or make this work? Maybe I am missing something from the Android documentation, but I couldn't find a way to support a VectorDrawable from outside of the res/drawables. Any help will be appreciative, thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `VectorDrawableCompat2` coming from? I can't find it in the support libraries.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I had the wrong stack trace in. I just updated with the correct stack trace for VectorDrawableCompat

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `VectorDrawable`/`VectorDrawableCompat` are wired to only working with resources. You might be able to fork `VectorDrawableCompat` and work around this. Off the cuff, the need for the `TypedArray` (from `obtainAttributes()`) is constrained to the `updateStateFromTypedArray()` method, called from `inflate()`. Perhaps you can replace `obtainAttributes()` and `updateStateFromTypedArray()` with code that can work with a plain `XmlPullParser`.

Comment: I've created a request for this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62435069

Comment: There is a comment in the Resources class that says: "XXX note that for now we only work with compiled XML files. To support generic XML files we will need to manually parse out the attributes from the XML file (applying type information contained in the resources and such).". So I believe it will not work for non-compiled XML resources =(

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to add the vector xml in drawable folder. Compile the apk. Unzip the apk and copy the compiled vector xml file from apk. Upload this vector xml to server. Download this file and inflate it dynamically.